# What setsockopts() 'name' values are used by the running Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, socket

I am introducing some new socket commands with `nf_register_sockopt(&my_new_socket_options)`. How can I find, what setsockopt commands are already used (registered?) by the currently running kernel, i.e. how do I safely choose `set_optmin` for my `struct nf_sockopt_ops my_new_socket_options`?

Comment: Best practice would be to tag some kind of unique namespace on to be safe (e.g., `foobar_set_optmin`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to search/check manually, but the call to `nf_register_sockopt` will fail if the range you're registering overlaps with the existing range. Here's a link to the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/netfilter/nf_sockopt.c#L24), which could use some comments, but you can see the overlap check at the beginning of the function. If you hop to `netfilter.h`, you'll see the lack of a function for inspecting the state of registered options.